# How do you stop Xcode 6.4 from creating its own provisioning profile (XC:) when building an archive

Tags: ios, xcode6

1. I have a distribution provisioning profile in the portal, say MyProvisioningProfile.
2. After going into Preferences/Accounts and clicking the refresh button I can see the provisioning profile fine.
3. When I produce an archive, Xcode creates a different provisioning profile named XC: .

I think that's the reason why I get the message 'No matching provisioning profiles found for My.app" and I click the Validate button.

How can I force Xcode to use the provisioning profile as defined in the portal instead of creating a new one?

Comment: are you clicking on fix issue button while build ?

Comment: No, I'm not clicking fix issue button.